# java regex "^\\d{1,4}\\,(.*?),"

Tags: java, regex

I have a code of line as:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{1,4}\\,(.*?),");
```

I want to understand what exactly is getting done in above regular expression,i.e.

```
"^\\d{1,4}\\,(.*?),"
```

Comment: It will match strings that begin with 1-4 digits, followed by `,` followed by one optional character, followed by a `,`. You can use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VIGYhg/1) to explore and understand regular expressions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d{1,4},(.*?),
```

Explaination:

- `^\d{1,4}` -- means must begin with between 1 to 4 digits (characters between 0 and 9)...
- `\,` -- means then there have `,`
- `(.*?)` -- means there will be any character 0 or more times but will happen 0 or 1 time...
- , -- means there is one more `,`

Look at this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZtJ4RK/5).. you will get better explaination here

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/6831257) answer to learn about regex.....

Comment: The question's broken formatting obscured the `*`; the expression is actually `(.*?)`

Comment: @tripleee updated. thanks. pls give  more improvement for this point. i can not explain clearly

Comment: It's a non-greedy match; but probably simply delete this answer and refer to the duplicate instead.